# Jquery update text works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code works fine except

```
 $('span.badgeAlert').text(counter - 1);
```

it only updates the number for the first click and then the page should be reloaded.

I have also tried ".live", but it did not work as well.

```
$('.remove_notification').on('click', function () {
var id = $(this).data('id');
var url = $(this).data('url');
var counter = $('span.badgeAlert').data('value');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: {notifiable_id: id},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#item_notification_'+id).remove();
        $('span.badgeAlert').text(counter - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

The markup is :

```
<li class="dropdown notification-dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell alertNotificacao"></span>
    <span class='badgeAlert' data-value="{{ DB::table('notifications')->count() }}">{{ DB::table('notifications')->count() }}</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="list-notificacao dropdown-menu">
 @foreach(\DB::table('notifications')->get() as $item)
     @if($item->type == 'App\Notifications\ArticleCreatedToAdmin')
        <li id='item_notification_{{ $item->notifiable_id }}'>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class='exclusaoNotificacao'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs button_exclusao remove_notification' data-id='{{ $item->notifiable_id }}' data-url="{{ route('notification.remove') }}">x</button>
                    </div>
                        <h5 class="media-heading"><a class="remove_notification" data-id='{{ $item->notifiable_id }}' data-url="{{ route('notification.remove') }}" href="{{ route('articles.show',$item->notifiable_id) }}">مقاله جدید</a></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
     @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 you can see the markup now :) thank you for your help

Comment: @gurvinder372, i have reversed the order as you said, did not work too.

Comment: What do you mean by *it only updates the number for the first click and then the page should be reloaded*, does the page reload currently and is that the problem? Or do you *want* the page to be reloaded after the first click?

Comment: @gurvinder372, i found the solution :
`var counter = $('span.badgeAlert').html();`
and it workded :) 
thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: yes, because laravel brought the value to the spam, and the counter had the same value add the time.

i had replace the var with let but the only was the value of the counter, anyway, thank you guys :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questioner found the answer already and mentioned in the comment.